how to resolve model importation conflict in flutter
I don't know what I did wrong here, everything was working well until I imported the ParishModel class and I started seeing some red lines. First was the CreateState() and when I hover around it, it says 'ShowAllParishPage.createState' ('dynamic Function()') isn't a valid override of 'StatefulWidget.createState' ('State Function()'). (Documentation)
The member being overridden (framework.dart:42) and the second error was from the State which says Try specifying a different superclass, or removing the extends clause. Please I need help on how to resolve it.
class ShowAllParishPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowAllParishPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);



  @override
  State<ShowAllParishPage> createState() => _ShowAllParishPageState();
}

class _ShowAllParishPageState extends State<ShowAllParishPage> {

  final Color color = Colors.blue.shade900.withOpacity(0.8);
  int dataLength = 0;
  bool fetchLoading = true;
  ParishModel? parishModel;



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<HomeBloc,HomeState>(builder: (context,state){
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900.withOpacity(0.8),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}


can you explain the question more clrealy?

I don't really know how to explain it but the issue only occurs when I imported that ParishModel class. The CreateState there will show red with the error message I posted

I don't know if it's a conflict in package or if it's from the fact that my state and event class extends Equatable

You can try importing the ParishModel with an 'as' so it would be something like import 'package:app/parish_model.dart as pModel'; and then you can call it using pModel.ParishModel

thanks so much @chumberjosh, it's not showing the error again. It's working perfectly
